# Is there an efficient way to create a lot of GMSMarker objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I used an overlay on the google maps as shown:

[image]

I have a UIButton button at the top right corner that filters markers using a UIPickerView.

Depending on the selection, I'm creating an X number of markers and placing it at the appropriate spots on the map.

The issue I have is having to manually do this:

```
GMSMarker *marker1 = [ [GMSMarker alloc] init];
GMSMarker *marker2 = [ [GMSMarker alloc] init];
GMSMarker *marker3 = [ [GMSMarker alloc] init];
GMSMarker *marker4 = [ [GMSMarker alloc] init];

....
```

Is there a quicker and more efficient way to create an X number of GMSMarker without repetitive code, ideally a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all the markers in an array(coordinatesArray).

```
NSArray *coordinatesArray = ......;
```

then

```
for(int counter=0; counter<[coordinatesArray count]; counter++)
{
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

    //----Below line is just an example, you'll get lat , lng from the array like the way.
    marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:counter]);

    marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

Hope this will help you.